# Managed Fusion as a Reverse Proxy

Tags: iis-7.5, reverse-proxy, managedfusion

I am trying (and failing) to set up a reverse proxy.

I have tried:

- [The Microsoft-specific way.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx)

  - Redirection works, but not URL re-writing (where the client doesn't see any change in the URL, but the request is handled by another website).
- [Using IIRF.](http://iirf.codeplex.com/)

  - This works on a test machine, [but the IIRF installation fails in production.](http://iirf.codeplex.com/workitem/32479)
- [Managed fusion.](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/)

  - I've configured this (I believe) correctly:

  > RewriteEngine On 
  >     RewriteRule ^/ping/(.*)  http://my.proxy.com/$1 [P,NC]
  >     RewriteLog "managed-fusion-log.txt"
  >     RewriteLogLevel 9

  I believe this works because I see this in the log file:

> 2013-01-08T13:49:41 **********************************************************************************
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 [Rewrite] Input: http://swisscom-live.emusetech.com:81/ping/somecall.svc
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 [Rule 0] Input: /ping/somecall.svc
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 [Rule 0] Rule Pattern Matched
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 [Rule 0] Output: http://my.proxy.com/somecall.svc
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 [Rewrite] Proxy: http://my.proxy.com/somecall.svc
>      2013-01-08T13:49:41 **********************************************************************************

However, the actual web browser shows me a 404 error from the "local" machine.  The logs say it's doing the right thing, but I can't figure out why it's not actually doing it!

---

Pointers appreciated! (On Managed Fusion or either of the other items).

---

**UPDATE:**  I finally managed to get the Microsoft-specific way working.  The trick (that I was missing) is that I needed to create a separate, empty Web Application and only create the reverse proxy on this new application.

I suspect that the other applications I was trying to add this to had some over-riding configurations which stopped URL-rewriting from working (but still allowed redirection).

Still interested in any comments on the Managed Fusion issue, though!!!

Comment: HI, I am facing the same issue. Could you please give me the steps for the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I moved the above solution to the production machines, it failed to work for URLs containing `.svc`.  It turned out that [this answer][5] to another question had the solution.

This ended up adding this to the web.config of the reverse proxy:

```
<system.web>
 <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
  <buildProviders>
   <remove extension=".svc" />            
  </buildProviders>
 </compilation>
</system.web>
```

so that service calls to the remote server were actually made, rather than interpreted locally.

And this had the upshot of also resolving the issue with Managed Fusion!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (404) when using managed fusion as proxy.

Apparently there is a **handler** to register in addition to the module that is not added automatically with the nuget package installation.

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="RewriterModule" type="ManagedFusion.Rewriter.RewriterModule, ManagedFusion.Rewriter" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="RewriterProxyHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="RewriterProxy.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```